# Randomly select n dates from pandas date_range

Tags: python, pandas

Given a date, I'm using pandas `date_range` to generate additional 30 dates:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta
pd.date_range(startdate, startdate + timedelta(days=30))
```

Out of these 30 dates, how can I randomly select 10 dates in order starting from date in first position and ending with date in last position?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- use [`np.random.choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) to choose specified number of items from a given set of choices.
- In order to guarantee that the first and last dates are preserved, I pull them out explicitly and choose `8` more dates at random.
- I then pass them back to `pd.to_datetime` and `sort_values` to ensure they stay in order.

---

```
dates = pd.date_range('2011-04-01', periods=30, freq='D')
random_dates = pd.to_datetime(
    np.concatenate([
            np.random.choice(dates[1:-1], size=8, replace=False),
            dates[[0, -1]]
        ])
    ).sort_values() 

random_dates

DatetimeIndex(['2011-04-01', '2011-04-02', '2011-04-03', '2011-04-13',
               '2011-04-14', '2011-04-21', '2011-04-22', '2011-04-26',
               '2011-04-27', '2011-04-30'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`numpy.random.choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) with `replace=False` if is not necessary explicitly get first and last value (if yes use another answer):

```
a = pd.date_range('2011-04-01', periods=30, freq='D')
print (pd.to_datetime(np.sort(np.random.choice(a, size=10, replace=False))))
DatetimeIndex(['2011-04-01', '2011-04-03', '2011-04-05', '2011-04-09',
               '2011-04-12', '2011-04-17', '2011-04-22', '2011-04-24',
               '2011-04-29', '2011-04-30'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```